# Snackbar expands when soft keyboard is showing

Tags: android, android-snackbar

I'm seeing a problem where the snackbar expands itself to fit the size of a listview on the screen when the soft keyboard is up.

**Snackbar with issue**
[image]

**Normal snackbar (keyboard not up)**
[image: Normal snackbar]

I've been able to slightly remedy this by setting the height programatically, however then the text disappears from the snackbar and I have no idea how to add it back.

```
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = snackbarView.getLayoutParams();
                lp.height = 150;
                snackbarView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

[image]

The snackbar is added as follows:

```
        mConnectionLostSnackbar = Snackbar.make(view, mConnectionLostString, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
        final View snackbarView = mConnectionLostSnackbar.getView();
        TextView textView = snackbarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
        textView.setLineSpacing(0, SNACKBAR_LINE_SPACING_MULTIPLIER);
        snackbarView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new NotDismissiblePreDrawListener(snackbarView));
        mConnectionLostSnackbar.show();
```

I would appreciate any thoughts on not having the snackbar expand when the keyboard is up. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have noticed that this only happens when the Snackbar is attached to a CoordinatorLayout that has ANOTHER CoordinatorLayout parent somewhere up the hierarchy. I guess the behaviour of <add as much bottom padding as needed to display the Snackbar above the keyboard> gets duplicated because of the multiple CoordinatorLayouts, and the Snackbar ends up taking the entire screen.

The solution is to attach the Snackbar to the topmost CoordinatorLayout. In my scenario I have an Activity with a CoordinatorLayout content view, that hosts a fragment that has a CoordinatorLayout as the root view. When the fragment needs to display a Snackbar, it attaches it to the Activity's CoordinatorLayout, and then it behaves correctly when the keyboard is displayed. Note that I am now using the AndroidX library instead of the support library, so the behaviour may be slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

The same happened to me, but I could not find the reason of the problem.

To avoid expanding the snackbar, I decided keep it behind the keyboard. This was achieved by adding this line to the desired activity on the manifest

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

I would really like to know why it happens, because on this project I use snackbar a lot and it only breaks on one activity

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I need the snackbar to remain visible in my use case.

Comment: Do you need the keyboard and the snackbar visible at the same moment? In my use case, I hid the keyboard and showed the snackbar, maybe that works for you

Comment: I need them both shown at the same time in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Just put this property in your `Manifest` file to your proper activity.

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
```